# Dapper C#: A parameterless default constructor or one matching signature error

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, dapper

I would like to get list of partitions for a given table.

```
public record Partition(string PartitionName, int OrdinalPosition);

public class MysqlService
{
    //...

    public IEnumerable<Partition> GetPartitions(string tableName)
    {
        using var conn = new MySqlConnection(_dbConnString);
        conn.Open();
        return conn.Query<Partition>(
            $"SELECT PARTITION_NAME, PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION " +
            $"FROM information_schema.partitions WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{tableName}';");
    }
}
```

But my code gives an error like

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: A parameterless default constructor or one matching signature (System.String PARTITION_NAME, System.UInt64 PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION) is required for Services.Partition materialization
    at Dapper.SqlMapper.GenerateDeserializerFromMap(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing, ILGenerator il) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 3297
    at Dapper.SqlMapper.GetTypeDeserializerImpl(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 3131
    at Dapper.SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.GetReader(IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.cs:line 151
    at Dapper.SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.GetReader(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.cs:line 50
    at Dapper.SqlMapper.GetTypeDeserializer(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 3085
    at Dapper.SqlMapper.GetDeserializer(Type type, IDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1835
    at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryImpl[T](IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command, Type effectiveType)+MoveNext() in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1105
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 734
    ...
```

How can I fix this?

I tried to use `UInt64` instead of `int` for the type of `OrdinalPosition`, but the same error occured.

**My Environment:**

- C# .NET Core Console Application (net6.0)
- Dapper 2.0.123
- MySQL 8.0

Comment: Did you notice the underscores between the word PARTITION and the rest of the column names? Your record has not  such underscores.

Comment: @Steve Is it needed to use same variable name with column name? I tried with `public record Partition(string PARTITION_NAME, int PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION);` just now, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Dapper doesn't automatically map data from table to property in some magical way. Or you have the same name for column and properties or you need to map them. However this is not enough here also the types should match. Uint64 is the type for PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types and names must match (or use a custom mapping).
You can use aliases to have "nicer" names in C#:

```
SELECT PARTITION_NAME AS PartitionName, PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION AS OrdinalPosition
FROM information_schema.partitions WHERE TABLE_NAME ...
```

`public record Partion(string PartitionName, uint64 OrdinalPosition)`

You should also deal with the potential SQL injection issue you have by
building a string with the WHERE-clause.

Dapper makes this easy enough:

```
public IEnumerable<Partition> GetPartitions(string tableName)
{
    using var conn = new MySqlConnection(_dbConnString);
    conn.Open();
    return conn.Query<Partition>(
        $"SELECT PARTITION_NAME AS PartitionName, PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION AS OrdinalPosition " +
        $"FROM information_schema.partitions WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName;", 
        new { tableName });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same Exception. You can create ctor like this:

```
public Partition(){ }
```